# Android: Click through the keyboard in edge to edge mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I use insets:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, root).let { controller ->
    controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    controller.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
}
```

Then when the keyboard is shown, it shows up without a bottom bar, and instead of a bottom bar, there is a blank area that you can click on. How can I disable clicks through it?
[image]